# Keeping certain patterns unevaluated

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often need to debug by preventing some definition from evaluating and checking intermediate results. I accomplish this by doing `initAll;clearAll[f,g,h]`. I don't like it because

1. It forces you to put everything in a single init block
2. It's not flexible enough to only keep certain patterns like `f[1]` unevaluated

Instead I'd like to have a list `forbidden` patterns and have any pattern that matches left unevaluated. How can I achieve this?

**Edit**
So far I found this pattern the most useful (it's Michael Pilat's answer except with HoldForm and BlankNullSequence)

`eh[expr_, symbols : {___Symbol}] := Block[symbols, HoldForm@Evaluate[expr]]`

Comment: ie, initAll:=(f[x_]:=x^2;p[x_]:=x^3)

Comment: Maybe something like Leonid Shifrin's custom evaluator https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/5a8711111d4b8fee is what you want?

Comment: He mentions that his evaluator might give different results than built-in. I'd prefer to use built-in evaluator, perhaps by temporarily modifying value lists. However, if doing it takes more effort than "initAll;clearAll[g,h]" or manually modifying definition of f[x_] to return unevaluated on f[1], it kind of defeats the point

Comment: Fair enough. I have to admit that I've used the `initAll;clearAll[f,g,h]` construction before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Block` can help with what you want:

```
f[x_] := x + 1;
g[x_] := x - 1;

In[13]:= Block[{f},
 Hold@Evaluate[(f[g[a]]^2)]
 ]

Out[13]= Hold[f[-1 + a]^2]
```

Do you want to prevent evaluation for certain down-value patterns of `f`? (E.g., block `f[x_]` but allow `f[x_, y_]`)?

**UPDATE**

Here's a functional form:

```
SetAttributes[EvaluateHeld, HoldAll];
EvaluateHeld[expr_, symbols : {__Symbol}] :=
  Block[symbols, Hold@Evaluate[expr]
]

In[7]:= EvaluateHeld[f[g[a]]^2, {f}]

Out[7]= Hold[f[-1 + a]^2]
```

Comment: Block constructions are magic... but they make my head hurt. This version `Block[{f = Hold[f[#]] &}, f[g[a]]^2]` makes a little more sense to me.

Comment: Michael, ideally yes, but not if it's harder than manually modifying definition of f each time I want to try to keep it unevaluated for particular kind of input

Comment: Is it possible to wrap this into a function? IE, so one could do `evalHeld[(f[g[a]]^2),{f}]`, and get the result above?

Comment: See my update =) I will also come up with something to block particular patterns of `f`, but I can't work on it until over the holiday as it's a bit more complicated and involves DownValue manipulation.